# Local copies of books are deleted off device when iCloud is disabled

Tags: icloud, books

So I made the fatal mistake of enabling iCloud on iBooks, when it has unresolved issues that people have been complaining about for years. Now I want to turn it off. Issue is, I can’t get my books back.

When I turned on iCloud, everything got uploaded and removed from my device. So I went through the tedious process of downloading hundreds of epubs one by one (these are all from external sources not the Apple Store). They all appear in ‘downloaded’ and are available offline. Then I turn off iCloud, and every single book disappears.

I’m on the latest available iOS (17.1.1) on my phone. This issue happens on my iPad as well.